# Invalid Prediction Results | PredictProba

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to classify youtube comments as Clickbait(label=1) or Fair/Non-Clickbait(label=0).

I've written the following code

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

training_data, testing_data = train_test_split(combine, test_size=0.3, random_state=2)

estimators = [('vectorize', CountVectorizer()),
              ('reduce_dimension', SelectKBest(chi2)), 
              ('var', VarianceThreshold()),
             ('classifier', LogisticRegression())
             ]
pipe = Pipeline(estimators)

param_grid = dict(vectorize__max_df=[0.90], 
                  vectorize__min_df=[3], 
                  vectorize__max_features=[1000, 700, 670, 850, 890], 
                  vectorize__stop_words=['english'],
                  reduce_dimension__k=[100],
                  var__threshold = [0.002],
                  classifier__random_state=[0],
                  classifier__solver=['lbfgs'])

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid=param_grid, cv = 5)
grid_search.fit(training_data['Tidy_Comments']
              , training_data['label'])

print("Test data: ")
print(testing_data.head(30))

predicted = grid_search.predict_proba(testing_data['Tidy_Comments'])
print(" \n Prediction Results: ")
print(predicted[:100])


                              ------------------------------

The output:

Test data: 
                                                comment  ...                                      Tidy_Comments
1604  OMG HAVE YOU SEEN WILBUR SCOOTS NEW VID ITS SO...  ...  omg have you seen wilbur scoot new vid it SO f...
849    Bro i saw a grapillaying hook in your. Inventory  ...           bro saw grapillay hook in your inventori
625   Now we know where the taliban got their weapon...  ...  now we know where the taliban got their weapon...
2482                  I like that I love you ðŸ˜˜â¤ï¸  ...                                 like that love you
1293          I love the song baby ðŸ’“ðŸ’“ðŸ’“ðŸ’“ðŸ˜  ...                                 love the song babi
2813  PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE TELL ME HOW THIS C...  ...  pleas pleas pleas pleas tell ME how thi channe...
171   They could change to melt in your mouth not O...  ...  they could chang to melt in your mouth not ON ...
4061  Ahh come on. All of those examples are just co...  ...  ahh come on all of those exampl are just coinc...
739   Paul IS SCARRED OF BRRROCCCK LESSSNERRRðŸ˜‚ðŸ˜...  ...               paul IS scar OF brrroccck lesssnerrr
2515  the ppl had such bad reactions to getting the ...  ...    the ppl had such bad reaction to get the airpod
3328                                             à¦¤à¦¾  ...                                                   
4284                                     How you doing?  ...                                         how you do
368      You should make a video about the mill grind 3  ...         you should make video about the mill grind
4089  Just saying. Not Danny Bonadoose. Danny Bonadu...  ...  just say not danni bonadoos danni bonaduch lea...
2247                                               Halk  ...                                               halk
3818                               Godzilla is that you  ...                               godzilla is that you
4180                     But Evee have more evaluations  ...                            but eve have more evalu
3614                    I want to see free guy unmasked  ...                        want to see free guy unmask
3527                    L like. YOur. VIdeo. JAke. PAul  ...                          like your video jake paul
3860  This site is experiencing multiple keter and e...  ...  thi site is experienc multipl keter and euclid...
1577                                          Rip dolph  ...                                          rip dolph
3336                          Why you are done put ring  ...                          whi you are done put ring
4126   I PUT MY EYES REALLY CLOSE TO IT AND IT LOOKE...  ...  put MY eye realli close TO IT and IT look like...
129                                                Good  ...                                               good
1298                                              A jay  ...                                                jay
1398  I slowed it down and why is rip beating loyd u...  ...           slow it down and whi is rip beat loyd up
3340                       Yes my daughter make a dolls  ...                           ye my daughter make doll
3223  I can do cool tricks with my tongue itâ€™s eas...  ...  can do cool trick with my tongu it easi just b...
744                            roman reigns vs goldberg  ...                            roman reign vs goldberg
3305                                                Red  ...                                                red

[30 rows x 3 columns]
 
 Prediction Results: 
[[0.80092569 0.19907431]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.53783207 0.46216793]
 [0.78627905 0.21372095]
 [0.08711146 0.91288854]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.58584449 0.41415551]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.51263466 0.48736534]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.18465366 0.81534634]
 [0.46557161 0.53442839]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.54056743 0.45943257]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.6883806  0.3116194 ]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.76529343 0.23470657]
 [0.07886884 0.92113116]
 [0.24400596 0.75599404]
 [0.53783207 0.46216793]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.14150512 0.85849488]
 [0.0713452  0.9286548 ]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.46557161 0.53442839]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.72834201 0.27165799]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.6583404  0.3416596 ]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.71652564 0.28347436]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.86098908 0.13901092]
 [0.78611001 0.21388999]
 [0.71191436 0.28808564]
 [0.31142753 0.68857247]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.58998975 0.41001025]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.5124826  0.4875174 ]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.46557161 0.53442839]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.81219853 0.18780147]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.1043104  0.8956896 ]
 [0.17718162 0.82281838]
 [0.91031567 0.08968433]
 [0.88660894 0.11339106]
 [0.17009882 0.82990118]
 [0.63742452 0.36257548]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.64319105 0.35680895]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.5124826  0.4875174 ]
 [0.80392858 0.19607142]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.28411768 0.71588232]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.46557161 0.53442839]
 [0.98244671 0.01755329]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.10581828 0.89418172]
 [0.73585843 0.26414157]
 [0.78018361 0.21981639]
 [0.53965163 0.46034837]
 [0.51263466 0.48736534]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.74754482 0.25245518]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]
 [0.46557161 0.53442839]
 [0.43872882 0.56127118]]
......... and more
```

so as you can see, the predict_proba prediction value is exactly the same for many of my test_comments even though the comments are completely different.
So can anyone help me correct this?

Comment: Please add a tiny portion of the data in the form of a code snippet @Ashish

Comment: @meti please check it again

Comment: very hard to tell, I would check 2 things, first how many features are used after each step, if you have too little, this could explain the prediction , second, the coefficients of the logistic regression, whether there's one thats really huge

Comment: @StupidWolf yes it was because of less number of features, thanks a lot.